# Implement a Custom Escaper in Freemarker

Tags: java, struts2, freemarker

Freemarker has the ability to do text escaping using something like this:

```
<#escape x as x?html>
Foo: ${someVal}
Bar: ${someOtherVal}
</#escape>
```

xml, xhtml, and html are all built in escapers. Is there a way to register a custom written escaper? I want to generate CSV and have each individual element escaped and that seems like a good mechanism.

I'm trying to do this in Struts 2 if that matters as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing two concepts here. ?xml, ?xhtml and ?html are string **built-ins**.
`<#escape>` OTOH is syntax sugar to save you from typing the same expression over and over again. It can be used with **any** expression, it's not limited to built-ins.

That said, there's unfortunately no built-in for csv string escaping and there's no way to write your own without modifying FreeMarker source (though if you do want to go this way it's pretty straightforward - take a look at `freemarker.core.BuiltIn`). Perhaps you can by with ?replace using regex or just write / expose an appropriate method and invoke it in your template.

Comment: This answers the question. It looks like it's more trouble than it's worth. I think I'll go the CSVWriter route instead of a template.

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc for [HtmlEscaper](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/api/freemarker/template/utility/HtmlEscape.html) indicates how to instantiate/register that in code (see the header), so I suspect if you implement your own [TemplateTransformModel](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/api/freemarker/template/TemplateTransformModel.html), and register it in a similar fashion then that should work.

Comment: I thought `<transform>` was deprecated?

Comment: I don't know, I confess. Certainly the classes referenced don't appear to be